# Dragging Folder Gets Stuck

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, nautilus, directory, drag-and-drop

I run three monitors and it seems when a file or folder is placed in the first column of the middle or right monitor it gets stuck there. I can no longer drag and move the file or folder from that spot. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and noticed that Nautilus has caused a similar issue with experimental features, but that doesn't seem to be that case for me.

Here is a gif if the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYFiV.jpg

It's not a debilitating problem, but it can get annoying. Any suggestions or solutions are appreciated.